# How to secure this simple radio communication against replay attacks

Tags: wireless

In my current project i have few ESP32's connected to server over TCP.
These ESP's are distributed across a range of 300 meters.

1. Once per hour server requests (randomly)  selected ESP's to beacon a frame over the air.
   These are called "**BEACONERS**"
2. At the same time, server requests few other (randomly) selected ESP's to sniff the air and look for these beacons, once found - return them to the server.
   These are called "**SNIFFERS**"
3. Each of them (Beaconer, Sniffer) have 30 seconds 'on-air'

The beacon frame goes out in plain text, it consists of a value that is known only to the **beaconer** and **server**. This value changes over time, beaconer never sends the same value twice.

Once received by **sniffer** the **beaconer**s unique id and value is returned to the server, which then validates if:

1. The beaconer's who's id was returned was asked to beacon (met 30seconds)
2. The sniffer who returned the data was asked to sniff (met 30seconds)
3. The value in the beacon matches the value on the server

High level

```
00:00:00 Server request -> Beaconer over tcp
00:00:00 Server request -> Sniffer over tcp
00:00:05 Beaconer -> Send beacon over radio [uniqueid,secret_value]
00:00:06 Sniffer -> Received beacon over radio [no checks]
00:00:07 Sniffer -> Forward this beacon to server over tcp
00:00:08 Server -> Validate input
```

All the communication happens plain-text, both beaconer's ID and value can be easily sniffed and replayed.

What mechanism can i implement to secure this simple communication against replay attack ? Can't think of any other that can happen really. With the server selecting beaconers/sniffers it is rather hard to replay anything, but still somebody could try to do it.

Comment: Secure against what?

Comment: @ThoriumBR i've added Replay attack at least.

Comment: Against replay attacks you can use a nonce.

Comment: @ThoriumBR nonce coming from server to beaconer as part of the request to beacon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nonce and digital signatures.

A nonce will make replay attacks impossible. If the nonce is incremented on every transaction, the beaconers and the server can keep the last sent beacon and any past beacon is invalid.

A digital signature can be used to prevent data on the beacon to be altered. The server can send the data plus a signature to the beaconers, signing the secret value plus the nonce.

In this case, an attacker cannot inject false beacons because he does not have the server secret, and cannot replay a past beacon because of the nonce.